# Use multiple models in laravel relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, entity-attribute-value

I'm working on a Laravel app which will be using [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) data structure. The required structure should be working as follow:

```
entity_types
 - id = 1
 - name = "Contact"


fields
 - id = 1
 - entity_type_id = 1
 - name = "First Name"
 - datatype = "text"

 - id = 2
 - entity_type_id = 1
 - name = "Last Name"
 - datatype = "text"

 - id = 3
 - entity_type_id = 1
 - name = "Phone"
 - datatype = "number"


entities
 - id = 1
 - entity_type_id = 1


values_text
 - id = 1
 - field_id = 1
 - entity_id = 1

 - id = 2
 - field_id = 2
 - entity_id = 1


values_number
 - id = 1
 - field_id = 3
 - entity_id = 1
```

Now the problem I'm facing right now is fetching all the values/fields from Entity Model. Basically I want something like using multiple models in HasMany Relationship so the base model can look through multiple tables. i.e.

```
public function values() : HasMany
{

    return $this->hasMany([ValueText::class, ValueNumber::class]);

}
```

I know there are some other plugins but they don't fully fulfill my needs and I wish to create a custom coded solution for this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think what you need is morphMany? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Or maybe `hasManyThrough`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: @Wreigh thanks for the hint mate! @Philip sorted it halfway through `hasManyThrough`. Problem solved! Thank you.